Vee-validate 'required' rule does not work on page navigation
In the following example in my application I can not make the vee-validate's required rule to work when using the browser's back and forward buttons.
Here is the code which does not work for me:
<script>
    export default
    {
        data() { return {v:undefined} },
        mounted()
        {
            this.$validator.detach("f")
            this.$validator.attach({name:"f", rules:"required"})
            this.$validator.validate("f", this.v);
        }
    };
</script>
<template>
    <v-text-field data-vv-as = f data-vv-name = f :error-messages = "errors.collect('f')" name = f v-model="v" v-validate = "'required'" />
</template>

Here I have a one text field f connected to the variable v. v is undefined.
I use vee-validate's built-in required rule for validation, what should create an error in that field on component load.
I manually detach and reattach the required field when component is mounted inside the mounted hook. Then I manually validate the f field.
This creates an error in the field.
However, if I go back and then forward, error is no longer visible although mounted does run, and validate method does get called.
If I refresh the page, everything works as expected again until I go back and forward again.
The reattaching is the key here, error only happens if I reattach the rule, but, if I do not, it does not.
Additional info:
In my real project, I need to manully reattach the validator because I use a combination of rules, which include the built-in required rule along a few custom ones which take custom parameters, but those parameters are dynamic, for example customRule:${this.dynamicParameter}, so, whenever the dynamic parameter changes, I need to reattach the rule, since vee-validate does not see the parameter updates to the rules (at least not in the version I use). That is why I need those two lines, detach and attach. But this example here is the most simplified one which reproduces the problem, so it might seam strange to do reattaching here without any good reason. But I do have a reason for that.
Versions I use are:
Vue: 2
Vuetify: 1
Vee-validate: 2
